# iOS local notification open specific view

Tags: ios, view, uilocalnotification

I would like to open a specific view because otherwise it would not make sense to make the notification.
On stackoverflow the majority of the questions are about tabbed app.. but I have a view controller.

This is my local notification:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
notification.alertBody = @"Test";
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

and this is the code that I have found for my app delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.mainVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTestViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.mainVC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
return YES;
}
```

I tried to integrate it into my app, but this is the error: Property 'mainVC' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'.

I would like to open 'MyTestViewController'. Can someone please explain to me how can I do? thank you very much

Comment: Where did you declare `mainVC`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a mainVC unless you've declared it somewhere. Assuming that you mean you want to set a view controller which is of the class MyTestViewController, you can do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    MyTestViewController *myTestVC = [MyTestViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = myTestVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

If your app is single view, you can use the "Single View Application" template in Xcode to get started.

[image]

Comment: @mamo10: If you are referring to the code above, it will show whatever is in your MyTestViewController's view. If it's transparent and contains nothing, black is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Import

```
#import MyTestViewController.h
```

create a property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MyTestViewController * myTestViewController;
```

And

```
self.myTestViewController = [[MyTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTestViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.myTestViewController;
```

Comment: You made a typo in property name.

Comment: app crash with this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/21C66BBC-70C3-43A8-83DA-C1A1282029EB/test.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyTestViewController''

Comment: You should have a MyTestViewController.xib file and its corresponding .h and .m classes too.

Answer (score 0):

Try it->

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    //present your controller here, for example
    self.myTestViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTestViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:self.myTestViewController animated:YES];
}
```